# In C does the logical operator end if one side of a || is true?

Tags: c

In C have the following:

```
return (abc(1) || abc(2));
```

If `abc(1 == 1)` returns `true` will then call `abc(2)`?

Comment: Why do you ask "In C does..." and you tag it C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abc(2)` will be called only if `abc(1)` is `false`

According to C99 specification, logical OR operator says

> The || operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand. If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.

Answer (score 9):

No, it won't.  This is called ["short-circuiting"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and it is a common flow-control mechanism:

With `a && b`, `b` is only evaluated if `a` is true; if `a` is false, the whole expression must necessarily be false.

With `a || b`, `b` is only evaluated if `a` is false; if `a` is false, the whole expression *may* still be true.

Answer (score 5):

No. It's guaranteed (by *The Standard*), that if `abc(1)` returns `true`, `abc(2)` will NOT be called.

If `abc(1)` returns `false`, that it's guaranteed, that `abc(2)` WILL be called.

---

It's similar with `&&`: if you have `abc(1) && abc(2)`, `abc(2)` will be called ONLY IF `abc(1)` return `true` and will NOT be called, if `abc(1)` return `false`.

---

The idea behind this is:

```
true OR whatever -> true
false OR whatever -> whatever

false AND whatever -> false
true AND whatever -> whatever
```

This comes from the [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)

Answer (score 3):

> If abc(1==1) returns true will then call abc(2) ?

No, it won't. This behavior is known as *short-circuiting*. It is guaranteed by C and C++ standards.

> #### C11(n1570), § 6.5.13 Logical AND operator
>
> Unlike the bitwise binary `&` operator, the `&&` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of
>   the first and second operands. **If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.**

(Emphasis is mine.)

The same applies to the `||` operator.

Answer (score 1):

`||` (logical comparison) breaks further checking, while `|` (bitwise comparison) doesn't.

You might also read: [Difference between | and || or & and && for comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279217/difference-between-and-or-and-for-comparison)

Answer (score 1):

nop, the second `abc(2)` is called only if the left statement is `false`

Answer (score 1):

In C, the logical `||` operator is tested from left-to-right, guaranteed.  For the whole statement to be true, either condition can be true.  So `||` keeps going from left to right until one condition is true, and then stops (or it gets to the end).  So no, if `abc(1)` returns true then `abc(2)` will not be called.

Contrast with `&&`, which keeps going from left to right until one condition is *false* (or it gets to the end).

Answer (score 0):

No. This is actually non trivial and defined in standard that logical operators are evaluated from left to right. Evaluation is stopped when the value can be determined with out further evaluation of operands. At least I am 100% sure for `AND` and `OR`.

This is non trivial problem, because therefore the evaluation of operands cannot be implicitly parallelized or optimized by reorganization of order, as the expected outcome could differ.

E.g. run-time troubles in wide-use cases such as `if (*ptr && (ptr->number > other_number) )`