# logical operators in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [A clear, layman's explanation of the difference between | and || in c# ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684648/a-clear-laymans-explanation-of-the-difference-between-and-in-c)
>   [What's the difference between | and || in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96667/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-java)

what is the difference between the operator | and the operator || ??
and also what is the difference between & and &&  ??

thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate of [A clear, layman's explanation of the difference between | and || in c# ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684648/a-clear-laymans-explanation-of-the-difference-between-and-in-c) Not about Java, but fully applicable here.

Comment: Also, [What's the difference between | and || in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96667/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-java)

Comment: i have read the ~ is not operator ... but i know that ! is the not operator ... can any one help me?

Comment: Look at the difference between logical and bitwise operators in general. `~` is just a bitwise 'not' (applied to integer types), while `!` is a logical 'not' operator (applied in boolean expressions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference is that in an expression `a && b`, `b` will not be evaluated if `a` is false, while in `a & b` both `a` and `b` will be evaluated no matter what. One can say that `&&` "**short-circuits**" the evaluation.

Similarly for `a || b`: `b` will not be evaluated if `a` is true, while in `a | b` both `a` and `b` will be evaluated no matter what.

Comment: you are missing any mention of bitwise.

Comment: But the topic asks for logical operators in java...

Answer (score 3):

`|` and `&` are available for booleans and integer types and don't short-circuit.

`&&` and `||` are only available for booleans and they do short-circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Single character | is [bitwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) OR operation, double || is logical OR

Single character & is [bitwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) AND operation, double && is logical AND

Comment: Would the downvoter please leave a comment. Thanks.

Comment: +1, the only answer mentioning actual purpose behind `|` and `&`.