# Difference between Bitwise and boolean operator 'AND'

Tags: java, if-statement, operators, bitwise-operators

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [logical operators in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005062/logical-operators-in-java)
>   [What's the difference between | and || in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96667/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-java)

As the title says, I need to know the difference between `&` operator and `&&` operator. 
Can anyone help me in simple words.

1. How do they differ from each other?
2. And which one to be used in a IF statement?

Comment: Guys, just 'cause it's likely a dupe doesn't mean it's not a real question... seriously...

Comment: @Mitch: You could have at least linked the duplicate.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann : since when was I appointed to perform the search that I'm sure the poster is able to do???

Comment: @Mitch: If you assert it is a duplicate, then you should link one. Even more if you say *many times over*. I had a short look and didn't find an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are in fact three "and" operators:

- `a && b`, with a and b being boolean: evaluate a. If true, evaluate b. If true, result is true. Otherwise, result is false.  (I.e. b is not evaluated if `a` is not true.)
- `a & b`, with a and b being boolean: evaluate both, do logical and (i.e. true only if both are true).
- `a & b`, where a and b are both integral types (int, long, short, char, byte): evaluate a and b, and do a bitwise AND.

The second one can be viewed as a special type of the third one, if one sees `boolean` as a one-bit integral type ;-)

As the top-level condition of an `if`-statement you can use the first two, but the first one is most likely useful. (I.e. there are not many cases where you really need the second and the first would do something wrong, but the other way around is more common. In most cases the first is simply a little bit faster.)

Answer (score 4):

If the first result is FALSE, `&&` doesn't evaluate the second result. `&` does.

Comment: is not *entirely* correct. There's another difference: The `&` operator is also the bit-wise AND operator, whereas && is not.

Comment: @Bohemian: One could say this is already in the question title.

Comment: @Bohemian: Click Edit on my answer, what you see might be interesting. :P (As to why I commented it out: Because part of it is wrong for Java, and part of it is a little redundant -- you can't use `&&` for integers anyway, so you can't really go wrong here.)

Answer (score 4):

&& only evaluates the second expression if the first operation is true. & evaluates both expressions (even if the first expression is false and there is no point in evaluating the second expression). Hence && is a tiny bit faster than & in logical operations. Hence && is also known as short-circuit and.

& can also be used as a bitwise operator in addition to a logical operator. So you can do a 'Bit And' of 2 numbers like for example

```
int result = 1 & 3; // will evaluate to 1
```

&& cannot be used as a bit-and operator.

For conditional IF operator, use &&. It is a tiny bit faster than just &.