# What is the difference between & and &&?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [& vs && and | vs ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014535/vs-and-vs)

What is the difference between `&` and `&&`?

I am getting same output for both `&` and `&&`.

### Ex:

1. `&&`:

   ```
   if (true && true){
       System.out.println("------if------");
   } else {
       System.out.println("------else------");
   }
   ```
2. `&`:

   ```
   if (true & true){
       System.out.println("------if------");
   } else {
       System.out.println("------else------");
   }
   ```

### Output:

1. `------if------`
2. `------if------`

Can we use `&` and `&&` operators in our code interchangeably?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795808/and-and-or-in-java-if-statements and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014535/vs-and-vs

Answer (score 2):

- `&` - bitwise AND
- `&&` - logical AND

You've true in both cases because in case of *logical* AND reason is obvious and in case of *bitwise* AND - true is interpreted as 1, so `1 & 1` alsays returns `1` which turns out into logical `true`

Comment: `&` works fine for booleans too. The operands are not "interpreted" as integers.

Comment: +1 for being the only real right answer here. & and && are actually two different operators. If I recall correctly, the fact that one uses full boolean eval and the other no, is just a side effect. you can use &= but I don't think you can use &&= in java.

Answer (score 2):

`&&` short circuits the evaluation, while `&` always evaluates both operands.

This is a duplicate question. I'll try to dig out the link for you...

- [logical operators in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005062/logical-operators-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

`&` will force the evaluation of both the left and right operands whereas `&&` is the short-circuit operator and doesn't check the right operand in obvious cases.

```
// this will evaluate both method calls even if the result
// of checkSomething() is false
boolean result = checkSomething() & checkSomethingExpensive()

// this will skip evaluation of checkSomethingExpensive() if the result of
// checkSomething() is false
boolean result = checkSomething() && checkSomethingExpensive()
```

Answer (score 0):

logical AND     &&

[Java operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

The bitwise & operator performs a bitwise AND operation.

[Java operators2](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb : use && when dealing with booleans, conditions, ifs, etc. I.e. most of the time. Use & in the rare cases when you need to perform bits operations.

Answer (score 0):

- &:  operation, boolean true & true == true, integer 1001b & 1110b == 1000b
- &&: comparison, boolean true & true == true, integer compiler error

Answer (score 0):

That's because the following is evaluated:

I will write it in english semantic for you to understand.

For output 1: Logical AND `&&`

> if true AND true IS TRUE.

For ouptut 2: Bitwise AND `&`

- Let x = true (in other words, bit `1`)
- x = x AND true (in other words, `x = 1 & 1`) Bit is AND'ed
- if (x IS TRUE) then print the if statement.

Answer (score -1):

&& is a comparison while & is an operation!